# jquery validate - hidden radio buttons, on show(); and interaction - "element is undefined"

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate

I have a form that shows/hides sections of the form based on checkbox select.

Part of the form that is hidden contains radio buttons:

```
<div class="input grid_4 alpha omega suffix_8">
        <label>Company Name</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" value="homeAddress" id="homeAddress" name="addressSelect">
        Home </label>
        <label class="radio inline">
        <input type="radio" value="bizAddress" id="bizAddress" name="addressSelect">
        Business </label>
        </div>
```

When I show that part of the form, and interact with the radio buttons, I get the following error:

Error: element is undefined
Source File: ..../js/jquery.validate.js
Line: 674

Line 674:
`idOrName: function(element) {
            return this.groups[element.name] || (this.checkable(element) ? element.name : element.id || element.name);
        },`

I tried ignoring the radio buttons based on name, but it still throws an error.
Additionally, if the radio buttons are not hidden (remove all show/hide functionality), there is no error.

Thoughts?

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/fBZQ3/

uncheck "this is also my shipping address" and then interact with the radio buttons.

Comment: What is the line causing all this?

Comment: @gdoron - I give the line number in the question, as well as additional information. I have edited the question to include a fiddle. As for whomever downvoted, reasoning should be included so that it can be addressed.

Comment: Try google the error message, it gave m several possibilities, I don't won't to write them all without knowing which is the one. just google `has no name assigned`

Comment: @gdoron - I've done that as well, prior to posting question.

Comment: I got no errors after simply assigning a name property to the checkbox.

Comment: @servarevitas3 - put that in an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks - it worked beautifully, and a stupid oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got no errors after simply assigning a name property to the checkbox.